# Google BigQuery: retrieve last version of each row

Tags: performance, google-bigquery, version

I have a Google BigQuery Table which contains all the versions of resources. Every time a resource is created/updated/deleted a new row is added incrementing the version number (this number will be the timestamp of when the row is added)

```
+-------+------------+--------+-------+-------------+
|  ID   | ResourceID | Action | Count |  Timestamp  |
+-------+------------+--------+-------+-------------+
| ABC_1 | ABC        | CREATE |    10 | {timestamp} |
| ABC_2 | ABC        | UPDATE |     8 | {timestamp} |
| ABC_3 | ABC        | UPDATE |     4 | {timestamp} |
| ABC_4 | ABC        | DELETE |     4 | {timestamp} |
| -     |            |        |       |             |
| DEF_1 | DEF        | CREATE |    10 | {timestamp} |
| DEF_2 | DEF        | DELETE |    10 | {timestamp} |
| -     |            |        |       |             |
| GHJ_1 | GHJ        | CREATE |    10 | {timestamp} |
| -     |            |        |       |             |
| KLM_1 | KLM        | CREATE |    10 | {timestamp} |
| KLM_2 | KLM        | UPDATE |     5 | {timestamp} |
+-------+------------+--------+-------+-------------+
```

- **ID**: a unique ID of the row, which contains the ResourceID plus the version identifier
- **ResourceID**: the ID of the resource where an action occured
- **Action**: The action occured on the resource
- **Count**: The value associated to the resource
- **Timestamp**: The timestamp of when the row has been added (which is the same attached to the unique ID)

I need a compose a query which retrieve all the last versions of each resource

```
+-------+------------+--------+-------+-------------+
|  ID   | ResourceID | Action | Count |  Timestamp  |
+-------+------------+--------+-------+-------------+
| ABC_4 | ABC        | DELETE |     4 | {timestamp} |
| DEF_2 | DEF        | DELETE |    10 | {timestamp} |
| GHJ_1 | GHJ        | CREATE |    10 | {timestamp} |
| KLM_2 | KLM        | UPDATE |     5 | {timestamp} |
+-------+------------+--------+-------+-------------+
```

In addition, all the resource which are in `DELETE` status, need to be ignored.
So here is the final output I'm looking for

```
+-------+------------+--------+-------+-------------+
|  ID   | ResourceID | Action | Count |  Timestamp  |
+-------+------------+--------+-------+-------------+
| GHJ_1 | GHJ        | CREATE |    10 | {timestamp} |
| KLM_2 | KLM        | UPDATE |     5 | {timestamp} |
+-------+------------+--------+-------+-------------+
```

This is the query I made

```
SELECT ResourceId, Count
FROM worklog_*
WHERE ID IN (
    SELECT max(ID)
    FROM worklog_*
    GROUP BY WorklogID
) AND Action != DELETE
```

It is not a true BigQuery query but it's enough to understand the behaviour.
This query works fine if the values of the ID column can be compared, this is why I choose to join ResourceId and Timestamp, the `MAX()` value will always provide the last status

Is this the best approach? Does anynone have a suggestion on a better way to do this kind of extraction?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH worklog AS (
  SELECT 'ABC_1' AS ID, 'ABC' AS ResourceID, 'CREATE' AS Action, 10 AS COUNT UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ABC_2', 'ABC', 'UPDATE', 8 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ABC_3', 'ABC', 'UPDATE', 4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ABC_4', 'ABC', 'DELETE', 4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'DEF_1', 'DEF', 'CREATE', 10 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'DEF_2', 'DEF', 'DELETE', 10 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'GHJ_1', 'GHJ', 'CREATE', 10 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'KLM_1', 'KLM', 'CREATE', 10 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'KLM_2', 'KLM', 'UPDATE', 5 
)
SELECT * EXCEPT(Last)
FROM (
  SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ResourceID ORDER BY ID DESC) AS Last
  FROM worklog
  WHERE Action != 'DELETE'
)
WHERE Last = 1
-- ORDER BY ID
```

Comment: Any explanation about the EXCEPT() clause in this specific case? I'm quite confused about how this works

Comment: EXCEPT allows you to exclude 'Last' field from final output

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you.

I thought EXCEPT is used for combining 2 or more results set and returning data that exist in resultset 1 but not exists in resultset 2.

I just know that EXCEPT can be used to exclude columns.

Comment: @Frais Afiriansyah: On the one hand, there is the EXCEPT operator that operates on sets and calculates their difference. This is implemented by most database system (sometimes also referred to as MINUS). On the other hand, BigQuery also offers keyword EXCEPT in the select clause right after an asterisk to exclude columns from being selected: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#select_except